# Delegate properties of Enumerable to class

Tags: ruby

I want to extend Enumerable methods to my class, so that I can call them directly on my class, and not on class's instance variable i.e. X.objects

```
class X
  include Enumerable
  extend Forwardable
  @objects ||= []

  # tried this, but it doesn't work
  # def_delegator self, :count, @objects.count
  #def_delegators self, @objects

  class << self
    attr_accessor :objects
  end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def save
    self.class.objects << self
  end

  def self.show
    objects
  end
end

y = X.new('a')
y.save
z = X.new('b')
z.save
n = X.new('c')
n.save
q = X.new('d')
q.save
p X.show
#p X.count # I want this to work.
```

Comment: To make Enumerable instance methods class methods of, for example, `Array`, you would need to execute `Array.extend Enumerable`. What then would, say, `Array.sort` mean (`sort` being an Enumerable method)? Enumerable methods have enumerators as receivers. The class `Array` is not an enumerator, so you would need to also define a class method `each` on `Array` (that returns an enumerator), so that Ruby could execute `Array.each.sort`. I have no idea where this is going...

Comment: I simply want my class to behave as an Enumerator, so that I can call methods directly on my class

Comment: Enumerator or Enumerable? These are two very different things!

Comment: Sorry for the mix up, I want my class to behave as Enumerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to define delegator on the class level

You may try to define it like this:

```
class << self
  extend Forwardable

  attr_accessor :objects
  def_delegator :objects, :count
end
```

I mean, the only difference between your code and this code is extending by `Forwardable` inside `class << self`